# Having multiple API tokens to be used in Angular Interceptors

Tags: angular, jwt, access-token, angular-http-interceptors

I have a very simple problem in my application where I'm trying to pass authentication tokens to my interceptor but I have different tokens for each API call.

How can I specify for each interception that the function should inject Auth Token X or Auth Token Y ? What would be the best approach?

I was thinking to add a variable inside the function calls telling it which token to be used but it would be a mess.

Comment: What I've done in the past is when the API call is made that a header is added such as "Auth Token X", and then the interceptor checks if that header exists on the request. If it does, then it replaces that header with the valid token for that API.

Comment: Its depends you can add a specify a custom header for differenciate the apis also you can check if is coming from URL "X" add X token, if coming from URL "Y" add Y token.

Comment: All of the requests are coming from the same backend service but each API requires a different Token for some reason. I thought about using reflect-metadata and decorators and decorate the functions with either tokenX tokenY but that did not work.